# In TestNG @Autowired object is giving null

Tags: spring-boot, testng

1. this is my first class to start the application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class PosApplication {
    
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(PosApplication.class, args);
        
    }
}
```

2. This is my second class and bean is defined and throgh testNGRunner method it will call Testme class

```
@Configuration
public class WebDriverLibrary {

       @Bean
       public  void testNGRunner()
        {
             TestNG testng=new TestNG();
              XmlSuite suite=new XmlSuite(); 
              List<XmlSuite> suites=new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();  
              suites.add(suite); 
              List<XmlClass> clazzes=new ArrayList<XmlClass>(); 
              XmlClass clazz=new XmlClass("com.pos.Testme");
              clazzes.add(clazz); 
              XmlTest test=new XmlTest(suite);
              test.setClasses(clazzes);     
              testng.setXmlSuites(suites); 
              testng.run();
        }
      }
```

3. this is my 3rd class and here i have autowired TestDemo Class and problem in this class. My Testme class run successfully but TestDemo is get autowired dependancy as null.

```
public class Testme {
    @Autowired TestDemo test;  // here i am getting null for test
    @Test
    public void Print() {
        System.out.println("Helo my child");
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void suite() {
        System.out.println("MY Suite");
        test.launchBrow();

    }
```

```
@Component
public class TestDemo {

    public void launchBrow()
    {
      System.out.println("Hit the Url");
    }
   }
```

Comment: have you tried extending your test class with `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`

Comment: Your field is null because despite it's `Autowired`, the instance has to be created by Spring but it is created by TestNg. Check this thread about spring and testng integration.